# Member function and expected primary-expression errors

Tags: c++

Here is my code, I am currently working on my own BigInt class and I am having some problems with getters and setters, and some program structure.
I keep getting these two errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':

prog.cpp:38:29: error: cannot call member function 'void bigInt::setString(std::string)' without object
  bigInt::setString(digString);                            
                   ^    
prog.cpp:39:28: error: expected primary-expression before 'void'
  cout << bigInt::getString(void);
                           ^
```

Code

```
//my bigInt class
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//class, constructors
//overload operators methods
//add, subtract, multiply, divide
class bigInt{//class
    public:
        bigInt();
        ~bigInt();
        void setString(string dig);
        string getString(void);
        std::string digit;
        std::string digString;
    private: 
        std::vector<int> big1;
        std::vector<int> big2;

};
//constructors
bigInt::bigInt(void){
}
//deconstructor
bigInt::~bigInt(){

}
void bigInt::setString(string dig){
    digit= dig;
}
string bigInt::getString(){
    return digit;
}

int main(){
    string digString= "90867537465982736459087162745938";
    bigInt::setString(digString);
    cout << bigInt::getString(void);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `main` you would do something like.

```
int main(){
    string digString= "90867537465982736459087162745938";
    bigInt my_int{};
    my_int.setString(digString);
    cout << my_int.getString();
}
```

You have to actually instantiate a `bigInt` object, which I called `my_int` in the above example. Then you can call the methods `setString()` and `getString()` off of that object.

The only class methods that you can call without having an instance to call them off of are `static` methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need an object to work with. Try in your main:

```
bigInt myInt;
myInt.setString(...);
```